# Count files and do something with it (using JHead in my case)

Tags: command-line

I have a folder with files 1.JPG, 2.JPG, ..., 12.JPG

Is there an expression to process all the files at once? I want to use a JHead command, but I think there is a general solution.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the processing you require is something like renaming 1.JPG to MyPicture1-320x480.jpg, and 2.JPG to MyPicture2-320x480.jpg, etc. then if you are using the Bash shell, you could change to the directory that contains the files and use something like:

```bsh
i=0; for n in *.JPG; do mv "${n}" "MyPicture${n/.JPG/-320x480.jpg}"; i=$((i+1)); done; echo "Processed ${i} files."
```

(The above can all be typed on one command-line.)

Or if you want to put it into a script, it would be easier to read and understand on multiple lines:

```bsh
# reset counter variable if you want to count the number of files processed
i=0

# loop for all files in current working directory that end with ".JPG"
for n in *.JPG
do
  # rename (move) each file from the original name (${n} is generally safer than $n)
  # to a new name with some text before the original name and then with the end of
  # the original name (".JPG") replaced with a new ending
  mv "${n}" "MyPicture${n/.JPG/-320x480.jpg}"

  # increment the counter variable
  i=$((i+1))
done
# display the number of files processed.
echo "Processed ${i} files."
```

If the processing you want is different to this, you might need to edit your question to provide more details.